# Show UITabBar while presenting a modal view

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, modalviewcontroller

When a user taps on a `UITabBar` item, I would like to present a view controller modally, but I would also like the `UITabBar` to remain visible. When the user is finished with the modal view controller I want to dismiss it modally. Basically, I want to show one view controller on top of another and dismiss the top view controller with a modal animation, while keeping the `UITabBar` visible. I am thinking I have to do some sort of custom animation, but I cannot figure out how to make that work.

Anyone know how to do this for iOS 6 and iOS 7?

Comment: The whole idea of a modal view controller is that it takes over the whole screen so you can't interact with anything else until you dismiss it, so it sounds like what you really want is not a modal presentation. Do you want the user to still be able to select a tab while this "modal" controller is on screen?

Comment: Yes, I want the user to still be able to interact with the tab bar. I don't really care if it is a modal view or not, but I do want it do be dismissed like a modal view.

Comment: I think you can do this with the new custom presentation method available in iOS 7. You'd have to write your own transition animation code, but unlike a normal modal transition, the custom methods (using the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate ) keep the presenting view controller's view in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal segues coverup the previous navigation controller stack, so any existing tab, navigation, and tool bar controllers will no longer accessible. You'll either need to use a push segue to retain the existing tab bar, or add a new tab bar controller to the modal view.